# How to find XPath without using contains

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I want to find Xpath for class 'body'.
but the problem is both the classes are there in another table also.

```
<td colspan="2" valign="middle"> 

<a style="display: block;text-decoration:none;color:#000;" href="/Pages/Requests.aspx?type=C"> 

<table class="special"> 

<tr style="height: 48px;"> 

<td class="single_td_width" align="center">● 

</td> 

<td align="left" class="body" style="color: #000; text-align: left;">End date</td> 

<td colspan="2" valign="middle"> 

<a style="display: block;text-decoration:none;color:#000;" href="/Pages/Requests.aspx?type=C"> 

<table class="special"> 

<tr style="height: 48px;"> 

<td class="single_td_width" align="center">● 

</td> 

<td align="left" class="classDate" style="color: #000; text-align: left;">Start date</td>
```

Comment: Why do you say in the title "without using contains"? I can't see why you would want to use contains, but I also can't see any reason why you would have a constraint not to use it.

Answer (score 2):

I see that 'td' has an text() attribute, so if the other 'td' with the same class attribute body has a different text(), you can probable to this:

```
"//td[@class = 'body' and text() = 'End date']"
```

if you are having multiple elements with the same attribute, you should probably use conditions like 'and' or do axes to go to that specific element. Like preceding-sibling, following sibling etc. You can see this website to learn how to do Xpaths Axes
http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_axes.asp

Comment: Thanks for reply, but is there any other way to find this, with out using contains , text , i want to declare this locator in yaml page

Comment: as Phillips mentioned, you can locate by index of array of 'td' like:
"//td[@class=body][1]", if you only have two td with that class attribute you wont have problem. The only cons is that if somehow this page updates and that array changes, you xpath will crash, that why I try to avoid index, as well that index may vary on browser.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the JavaScript DOM getElementsByClassName instead? But in XPath it's just

```xml
//*[@class="Body"]
```

Comment: Hi philip, I have two classes with same names as mentioned above but I want to get the second class value i.e., Start Date.

Comment: Oh gotcha, use `(//*[@class="Body"])[2]. It might be indexed by 0, can't remember tbh xpath actually does both which is another story, so could be [1] or [2]. I hope that is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath,

```
//td[@class='body']
```

will select all `td` elements in the document with `@class='body'`.

If you have more than one, you need to tell us how they're different and which one you wish to select.  Absent that, all we can say is that

```
(//td[@class='body'])[1]
```

is the first such `td`, and,

```
(//td[@class='body'])[2]
```

is the second such `td`.